# How To set up SNMP manager and Agent

Tags: network-programming, snmp, net-snmp

I am new to network programming. 
I have learnt the basics of SNMP and now I want to test out the commands.

I need to know what are the software tools available to set up SNMP manager and also to simulate SNMP agent. I would prefer opensource tools in linux.

Also suggest the pre-requisites to start coding for SNMP in C/C++, like libraries, compilers, IDE etc.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Linux [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) is what you're looking for.